# html transparent background

Tags: html, css, background, transparent

I want to create a webpage with transparent background, a table and some text. I have seen posts related to this, but due to my lack of familiarity with css, I somehow cant get my code to work. I just want a transparent background, while this code is making everything transparent. Can someone kindly help.

```
<html>
<head><style type="text/css">
  div.transbg {background-color:#4a6c9b; opacity:0.6;}
</style></head>
<div class="transbg">
<body><Center><font color="#FFFFFF">
  <b>Toll Charges</b>
  <table bgcolor="#000000" cellspacing=3>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#009900"><font color="#FFFFFF" align="left"> &nbsp; &nbsp;Class 2 inc Private&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td bgcolor="#009900"><font color="#FFFFFF" align="right"> &nbsp;A$ 4.95 &nbsp;</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#009900"><font color="#FFFFFF" align="left"> &nbsp; &nbsp;Class 2 inc Commercial&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td bgcolor="#009900"><font color="#FFFFFF" align="right"> &nbsp;A$ 13.95 &nbsp;</font></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    Toll has to be paid within 48 hrs of passage, else an additional A$ 13.95 of administration charges would be added
    </font></Center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

Great thanks for all the answers people. I have solved the problem in another way for the moment. Actually, I writing an iPhone app which uses Webview to display some html. I wanted to give webview a transparent look, which can be achieved by setting the alpha for the webview itself in interface builder. It kinda saying, make my entire web browser 50% transparent. I would like to thank everyone for their help here.

Comment: P.S: `<font>` and `<center>` are deprecated since 1998(!!!). Please throw that vintage HTML tutorial/book you're using away and go get a recent one.

Comment: Yes, these days, formatting should be done in the CSS. Just imagine it as all your attributes like `<font>` and `bgcolor` being all done in one location. This way you only need to use the class attribute to determine the style.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for this,

```
.transbg {
    background-color:#4a6c9b;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
-moz-opacity:0.6;
-khtml-opacity: 0.6;
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

and maybe this http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: His problem was rather that "everything" becomes transparent, not that it doesn't work in IE<8 or the >2 year old Gecko/KDE browser engines.

Comment: I recite: *"while this code is making everything transparent"*. Thus transparency works perfectly. It's only not what he expected.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using rgba instead of opacity, thusly:

```
.transbg {background: rgba(red,green,blue,opacity);}
```

You can also put the rest of your formatting into CSS like this:

```
body {background-color:#000;
      color:#fff;}
td {background-color: #090;
    color:#fff;}
.leftc {text-align:left;}
.rightc {text-align:right;}
table {borderspacing: 3;}
```

Now you can remove the font tags and the attributes of td. All you'd need for td is `<td class="leftc">` or with the `rightc` class for text to the right.

See also http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 2):

I recently discovered that I wanted to create an HTML body with a transparent background.  (The HTML is a localized information page of instructions for an app, and will appear a "browser" that is really just a Webkit view within another set of views. The Webkit view sits on top of an image in the view hierarchy. By making the web page  background transparent, the image from the view behind the Webkit view shows up.)

To accomplish this, just code the HTML as follows, together with any other  attributes/styles/etc:

```
<body bgcolor=transparent>
```

In other words, use the keyword "transparent" *without* the quotes, and you will get an alpha of 0 and thus a transparent background to allow whatever is behind to show through.

(Caveat: In the Webkit view implementation I have, I also have to make the Webkit background color transparent in my UI setup.  I.E. both must be in place for this to work as I have it.)

Comment: just came across this whilst looking and I know its an old question but `bgcolor` has been deprecated and shouldnt be used - https://caniuse.com/#search=bgcolor

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your requirement makes sense. Just give the background the desired color.

```
div.transbg { background-color: #92a7c3; }
```

Transparency is only interesting for background images or overlayed backgrounds, which doesn't seem to be applicable in your particular case.